# How to remove text after certain word in DB using query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have situation like in my DB I have links like

```
http://www.myurl.com/url-blog/entry/camel-shadows-pic-amazing-.htmlhttps://www.testurl.com/gatoradecoupons

http://www.myurl.com/url-blog/entry/cat-mountain-at-ukraine.htmlhttps://www.testurl.com/user/212294
```

I want to remove the text after `.html` . The catch is I want to remove the text beyond `htmlhttps`. We can check if the URL has this and to trim rest of the text except `.html`

The desired output

```
http://www.myurl.com/url-blog/entry/camel-shadows-pic-amazing-.html

http://www.myurl.com/url-blog/entry/cat-mountain-at-ukraine.html
```

There are thousands of such URLS in DB . I wonder if there's any way to remove in one go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this uses `substring_index()`:

```
select concat(substring_index(url, '.html', 1), '.html')
```

If some values don't have `.html`, then the above will add it.  For that, you can use `case`:

```
select (case when url like '%.html%'
             then concat(substring_index(url, '.html', 1), '.html')
             else url
        end)
```

And, once you have tested with a `select` you can update the value if you want:

```
update t
    set url = concat(substring_index(url, '.html', 1), '.html')
    where url like '%.html%';
```

Comment: just wondering, is it possible to create that `select `query by using `if()` instead of `case`? anyway, interesting usage of `case` in SQL, never seen it before. don't blame me, my knowledge on this subject is just above basics.

Comment: @Gordon Thank you so much . But how do I use the `url` in your query?  I have a column in a table which has the Urls . All URLs have `.html ` extensions .Some are with incorrect format with  `htmlhttps` and some are correct end with `.html` and no need to correct them

Comment: @Gordon The 1000s of urls are in `select loc from mytable ` how do I use this is your query ? Please help

Comment: @user41048 . . . You replace `url` with `loc` in the code and add a `from` clause to the query.